# "echo >/sys/..." doesn't take effect when using >/dev/null 2>&1

Tags: bash, io-redirection

This is somehow weird. I'm trying to scan an iscsi device using the following command:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan >/dev/null 2>&1
# Doesn't work. The rescan won't recognize the new available disk space. 

echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
# Works: recognizes the new available disk space.
```

How can I send all stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, since I don't want my screen to get messy?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan >/dev/null 2>&1
       ^                              ^
```

You have two output redirections here. The latter one takes effect, so this is equivalent to:

```
echo 1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which doesn't write anything to files in `/sys`.

The command you're running here is `echo`, which only prints to stdout what you ask it to print on the command line, so it's not going to print anything "surprising" there. Also, while you might get errors if the first redirection cannot be opened, they're likely to come when the redirection is processes, i.e. from the shell, not the command itself, so even the `2>` redirection might not do anything.

On the other hand, if triggering that rescan causes output somewhere, it's likely to come from the kernel, through the usual logging mechanisms. So you'll need to check what the logging configuration is to control that.

If you're using a Linux virtual terminal, some kernel messages get printed on the active vt. You can use [`dmesg -n<level>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) to set the priority level of messages of messages going to the console.

Comment: Still not working. I've tried the short version as well before posting and it did not work.  I tried 2>/dev/null` as well without success.  It seems that 2>&1 is messing up the whole command.

Comment: @holasz you’ll need to explain what you’ve tried in a little more detail then. The most important part in ilkkachu’s answer is the last paragraph — redirecting output isn’t going to help you avoid error messages here.

Comment: @holasz, what output do you get that messes your screen? I added a bit longer explanation just before your comment came in.

Comment: I think the last part of the answer indeed solved my problem. This was coming from kernel and I solved it using this link: https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console   Thank you !

Comment: @holasz, yeah, `dmesg -n1` to silence almost everything at runtime or that sysctl.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks again.  It was the kernel and I wasn't thinking clearly.  Problem solved!